# How to create a byte[] of unknown size in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a byte[] given some unknown amount of bytes. Here's an example:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.Add(0xCA);
al.Add(0x04);
byte[] test = (byte[])al.ToArray(typeof(byte));
```

I'm receiving an error that one or more of the values in the array cannot be converted to a byte. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either use a generic collection instead of a nongeneric `ArrayList`, or make sure you are actually using bytes.  0xCA is an `int`, not a `byte`.

```
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.Add((byte)0xCA);
        al.Add((byte)0x04);
        byte[] test = (byte[])al.ToArray(typeof(byte));
```

Comment: ah, I thought the 0x made it into a byte. My bad.

Comment: no, 0x just makes it a hexadecimal integer, any 0x number below 8 digits is thought an Int32 (but implicitly castable to byte/short if the number of digits is below 2/4 respectively)

Comment: Using ArrayList you are boxing and unboxing the bytes to objects which can produce a significant performance hit.  Using the generic List<byte> prevents the boxing from occuring and gives better performance.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, in general generics are a much better way to solve this problem.  My answer is more about telling the OP why his code won't work than offering the best way to accomplish the task.

Comment: @FoppyOmega : Unfortunately, there isn't any way to explicitly create a `byte` literal.  C# does have suffixes to create some of the numeric literals (e.g. `m` for `decimal`), but for bytes you'll need to use an explicit or implicit cast.

Answer (score 11):

Try `List<byte>` and then use ToArray

Comment: ..what would happen to al.Add(0xCA); with List<byte> ? Compiler error?

Comment: no, the generic Lists only allow you to add the Generic type, and 0x numbers are implicitly castable to lower types (than their default Int32) if they are small enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<byte>` like below. When you are using ArrayList and then calling al.Add(0xCA) you are actually adding int's to the ArrayList.

```
List<byte> al = new List<byte>();
...
```